# Browser refreshes html file twice when using Visual Studio Code with Live Server or Browser-Sync

Tags: visual-studio-code

For testing purposes, I have a simple html file that contains two lines of Javascript.  I'm using Visual Studio Code (version 1.29.0) with the Live Server extension (version 5.1.1).  With the html file loaded in the browser via Live Server, whenever the html file is saved, the browser refreshes (producing a random number in the console).  After roughly 1 second, the browser will refresh again (producing a different random number in the console).  It does this every time I save the file.  The same issue occurs when I try it using Browser-Sync.

I've tried this with Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Edge. They all exhibit the same behavior.

I've been using Visual Studio Code for several months and this wasn't happening until recently that I can remember.  I've toggled all of the settings in VSCode that I think might be relevant to the problem, but can't seem to find the issue.

Any ideas as to what is making the browsers refresh twice?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Javascript Sandbox</title>
</head>
<script>
  var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  console.log(a);
</script>
<body>
  <h1>Javascript Sandbox</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.  I use Windows 10.  The problem has to do with OneDrive.  My html file is stored in a folder within my OneDrive folder. I have that folder set to "Always keep on this device", which means it's stored as a local copy.  However, when I copy the file onto my Desktop and run it from there, the browser only refreshes once.

Comment: I was trying to figure out this issue for so long! I use Google Drive and didn't event thought that it may cause the problem. thank you!

Comment: The exact same thing happens with Google Drive as well. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: I really appreciate this information, thanks